# Barplot returns unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I try to plot a bar plot of a pivot_table with the following code:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.bar(Products.index,Products["Amount"].values)
```

The pivot table is like:

```
                                      Amount
Material                             
454T006S R 167 134:11                0.000000
3457T006S R IE216 167 246:1          4.500000
67T009S R 1510K304:1              36.000000
7676009S R IE216 1510K304:1        30.500000
676T012S 167 246:1                  1.000000
2324T012S R 1510 111                6.000000
1516T012S R 1510 151               50.500000
1516T012S R 1510 20:1               26.500000
```

But it returns:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is your index values are `strings`.

I think simpliest is use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
Products["Amount"].plot.bar()
```

You can map values of string to `range`, plot range and last add `xticks`:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)

idx=Products.index.tolist()
x = range(len(idx))

plt.bar(x, Products["Amount"].values)
plt.xticks(x, idx, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Similar solution is `reset index` and plot by default `index`:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)

Products = Products.reset_index()
plt.bar(Products.index, Products["Amount"].values)
plt.xticks(Products.index, Products['Material'], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```